# Prove that $\pi$ is a transcendental number

Tags: pi, transcendental-numbers

Does anyone has a link to a site that confirms that $\pi$ is a transcendental number?

Or, can anyone show how to prove that $\pi$ is a transcendental number?

Thank you in anticipation!

Comment: http://www.math.sc.edu/~filaseta/gradcourses/Math785/Math785Notes6.pdf

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12872/how-hard-is-the-proof-of-pi-or-e-being-transcendental this question might be of some interest

Comment: Also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/21367/proof-that-pi-is-transcendental-that-doesnt-use-the-infinitude-of-primes

Answer (score 18):

As suggested by Yuval's comment, the most straightforward way of showing that $\pi$ is transcendental proceeds through the [Lindemann–Weierstrass theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) that $e^x$ is transcendental if $x$ is (nonzero and) algebraic; since $e^{i\pi}=-1$ is algebraic, then $i\pi$ must be transcendental, and therefore $\pi$ must be (since $i$ isn't rational, but it *is* algebraic!).  You can find a rough proof of the theorem at its Wikipedia page.

Answer (score 10):

Try the short paper [The transcendence of $\pi$](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2302515) by Niven 
and his book [Irrational Numbers](http://www.maa.org/press/ebooks/irrational-numbers).

Comment: This paper has been reproduced in Appendix A of Jonathan M. Borwein and Scott T. Chapman, "[I Prefer Pi](https://carma.newcastle.edu.au/jon/31415.pdf): A Brief History and Anthology of Articles in the American Mathematical Monthly", American Mathematical Monthly, Volume 122, Issue 03, pp. 189 - 296, March 2015 (downloadable from https://carma.newcastle.edu.au/jon/31415.pdf from the first author's web page at https://carma.newcastle.edu.au/jon/index-papers.shtml).