# References on $\pi^{n}$ is transcendental

Tags: reference-request, transcendental-numbers

I am looking on references showing that $\pi^{n}$ is transcendental for $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
Which one do you recommend?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well, since $\pi$ is transcendental, $\pi^n$ is obviously transcendental... except when $n=0$.

Comment: $\pi^{n}$ is of course transcendental, if $\pi^{n}$ is not transcendental meaning $\pi^{n}$ satisfying some polynomial $P(x)$, then $\pi$ satisfying some polynomial $P(x^{\frac{1}{n}})$ contradiction.

Comment: @ZackNi You mean $\pi$ is a root of $P(x^n)$, not $P(x^{\tfrac{1}{n}})$.

Comment: Okay then but where can I read that $\pi$ is transcendental? :)

Comment: @simon Yes Sorry a logical fallacy.

Comment: @op possibly duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31798/prove-that-pi-is-a-transcendental-number

Answer (score 1):

If $\pi^n$ were algebraic, for some $n\ne 0$, then there would an $m\in\mathbb N$ and $a_0,\ldots,a_m\in\mathbb Z$, with $a_ma_0\ne 0$, such that
$$
a_m (\pi^n)^m+a_{m-1} (\pi^n)^{m-1}+\cdots+a_0=0,
$$
but that would mean that $\pi$ is also algebraic!