# A proof that $e$ or $\pi$ is irrational via algebraic integers

Tags: matrices, number-theory, recreational-mathematics, integers, transcendental-numbers

A very brief proof to show that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational goes like this:

*We know that $\sqrt{2}$ is an algebraic integer. If it is rational it should be an integer which is not therefore it is irrational.*

Now the question is that can we use a similar proof for showing that $e$ or $\pi$ are irrational?

I mean is there a proof of existence or non-existence of an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ of integers whose eigenvalue is $e$ or $\pi$?

Comment: $e$ and $\pi$ are transcendental...so no such matrix exists.  But this is not an elementary result.

Comment: Elementary result? So you mean we can write a proof for non existence?

Comment: [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12872/how-hard-is-the-proof-of-pi-or-e-being-transcendental) is a good general discussion of some of the ideas.  $e$ is easier to work with and a sketch of the proof can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number).

Comment: there are elementary proofs that $e$ is irrational.  [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_e_is_irrational) for instance.  Transcendence is more subtle.

Comment: Great reference, thanks!

Comment: Showing that $e$ is irrational using that $e$ is transcendental?

Comment: @GEdgar That would be trivial, since all transcendental numbers are also irrational.